# Detect when external link has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link to a URL that returns a download PDF dialog box

It takes about 30 seconds to load so I would like to present some visual indication to the user that they've clicked the button and that the PDF has been requested.

As the PDF loads in a dialog box so it can be saved, the user isn't redirected to another URL in their browser. After they've clicked the save the PDF they remain on the same page.

Is there anything I can do with Javascript (or jQuery) to detect when the PDF has loaded and the dialog box has been presented? If so, then when I receive this event then I can hide the loading icon that I'd like to display when the link is first clicked.

Comment: Is the dialog box something like a modal or another browser window?

Comment: Doubt there is anything you can do

Comment: If you are using `iframe` to load the pdf document, then iframe has `onload` event which can be used to trigger a function that hides loading icon.

Comment: Same window - i.e. you click a link to download a PDF and then your browser prompts you to download the file